# Connecting VisualVM windows to Wildfly 16

Tags: wildfly, visualvm, thread-dump, wildfly-16

How can i connect VisualVM to Wildfly 10?

I have put jboss-client jar in following folder and started visual vm:
[image]

Then i started visual vm
[image]

When i added jmx connection i get following:
[image]

Can anyone suggest what is wrong here? I have not put any authentication (not sure what authentication will it have as console have admin/pass but no password set anywhere else).

Can anyone suggest what is wrong here?

(I have multiple server groups and not sure where to add "remoting-connector use-management-endpoint="true" in domain.xml. I have added in 1 server group only.)

Answer (score 6):

You need to extend VisualVM classpath (using "--cp:ad") with JBoss client jar, eg:

```
jvisualvm --cp:a $WF_HOME/bin/client/jboss-cli-client.jar
```

Then connect to your wildfly on admin port (usually 9990)

```
service:jmx:http-remoting-jmx://localhost:9990
```

See interesting article here:
https://nozaki.me/roller/kyle/entry/articles-wildfly-visualvm

Comment: Hi, Thanks what about difference server groups

Comment: Here is the document from RedHat https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.3/html/performance_tuning_guide/monitoring_performance